# How to render html content into PDF invoice?

Tags: magento-1.8, template, magento-community, pdf, html

I'm trying to print some payment info using html tags, like `<strong>` and `<p>`, but it's not working. I have this function in a file `Info.php` within the payment module:

```
public function toPdf() {
    $this->setTemplate('MOIP/transparente/info/pdf.phtml');
    return $this->toHtml();
}
```

And inside `pdf.phtml`, I have:

```
$info = $this->_prepareInfo();
<p>Method: <strong>Credit card</strong></p>
<p>Payment way: <strong><?php echo $info['creditcard_parc']; ?></strong></p>
<p>Flag: <strong><?php echo $info['cc_flag']; ?></strong></p>
<p>4 last digits: <strong><?php echo $info['last4'] ?></strong></p>
```

But, the output is not being the expected. There are 2 issues:

1. The lines are breaking unnecessarily.
2. The credit card icon is printed out like when we use `htmlspecialchars`, instead of the image rendered as it should.

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, at least not with default PDF implementation which is `Zend_Pdf`. Look at following classes for reference:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Abstract
```

Comment: Any more information as to why this cannot be done would help here I think.

Comment: Because the Zend_Pdf library doesn't support HTML. For HTML to PDF use TCPDF or DOMPDF